# Detecting Unique Browser Tabs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

On every page of my sites, I am using AJAX to poll the server and retrieve a list of messages. The server maintains a list of messages and the SessionId (I'm in an ASP.NET environment, but I feel like this question is applicable to any server side technology) that the message is intended for. If a message is found for the particular SessionId, it is returned to the client side script. I use a JavaScript library to create a notification (using [noty](http://ned.im/noty/), a Jquery Notification Plugin). Once it returns a particular message, the server discards that message.

This works well if the user only has a single tab/window open for a particular site. However, let's say they have two open and they do something that causes a warning message to be generated. I have no control over which tab the notification goes to, so the user may not end up seeing the warning message.

Is there a way of uniquely identifying a browser tab? Then I could pass this as one of the parameters in my AJAX call.

Comment: window.MYID=Math.random(); ... doServerStuff(MYID, ...); ... if(response.id==MYID) ...  you can use window.name to persist the ID across refreshes.

Comment: @dandavis Would that last across multiple requests? Let's say I set window.MYID on Default.aspx and then the user navigates to MyAccount.aspx. Would window.MYID still be initialized to the same value?

Comment: window.MYID would not, but window.name would. You could also use sessionStorage if it's available.

Comment: Do you mean that user is taking a not allowed action in one of the browser tab and you want to show a message in another browser tab?

Comment: No. I want an AJAX based message system that sends the message back to the correct tab. For example, user does some action on tab X that's not allowed, I want to show a message on tab X. But I want the same system to allow also redirecting the user to another page and still displaying the message on tab X, not tab Y.

Comment: ok. I've replied to you question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, polling doesn't seem good mechanism. It might hit your server down when you have large number of active users. Ideally you should return a message in the response to the request that was result of invalid action.

Still below solution might work for you. It is inspired by the reply of @SergioGarcia.

Keep a hidden input just before the end of your form tag, which stores a unique ID for identifying a tab uniquely. You will store the messages on server session against unique tabID,

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInputTabId" value="<%=getValue()%>" />
```

and then define `getValue`.

```
function string getValue() {
    var v = getValueFormBodyOrAccessValueDirectlyByMakingInput_a_ServerSideControl();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)) {
        return Guid.NewId();
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Because it is a hidden input you should get it's value in the POSTed form body, and for ajax requests below snippet should take care of sending that value in header which [you can access on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530134/148271).

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("tabId", $('#hiddenInputTabId').val());
    },
});
```

Same header can be check while returning the response to your polling requests and only respond message available against the provided tabId should be responded.

Comment: I agree, polling is not a good idea. I'm looking into using SignalR as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query string parameter called `tabId` and control it's binding to tab using javascript.

There is a functional prototype below:

```
$(function () {

  // from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location
  function getQueryStringParameter (sVar) {
    return decodeURI(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURI(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
  }

  // from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript
  function newGuid() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
  }

  window.tabId = getQueryStringParameter('tabId');

  // tabId not defined, reload the page setting it
  if (!window.tabId) {
    window.tabId = newGuid();
  }

  // on click set the tabId of each link to current page
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newLocation = $(this).attr("href");

    // In page links
    if (newLocation.match(/^#.+$/)) {
      return;
    }

    // Outbound links
    if (newLocation.match(new RegExp("^https?")) && !newLocation.match(new RegExp("^https?://" + window.location.host))) {
      return;
    }

    // Insert tab id
    if (newLocation.match(/(\?|&)tabId=[0-9a-f-]+/)) {
      newLocation.replace(/(\?|&)tabId=[0-9a-f-]+/, (newLocation.indexOf('?') == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "tabId=" + window.tabId);
    } else {
      newLocation += (newLocation.indexOf('?') == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "tabId=" + window.tabId;
    }

    window.location.href = newLocation;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

If you enter a page in your application without setting the `tabId` parameter on query string, it will be set to a new UUID (Guid).

When the page has a `tabId` parameter on query string, it defines the `window.tabId` variable inside your page and you can use that in your application.

When the user click on any link in your page, a javascript event will be triggered and the link url will be redirected to match the current `tabId`. An right click to open in new tab or a middle click will not trigger that event and the user will be sent to a new tab without the query string parameters, so the new page will create a new `tabId` in that page.

You can see it working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sCcvK

Comment: I like where you're going with this. I dislike using query string to pass it around, but I guess that's a good serverside-agnostic solution.

Comment: Depending on the technology used in the server side, it can be part of the route, in ASP .net MVC could be `/{tabId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}` for example.

Comment: Well, that's just avoiding the problem. It's still in the URL. Ideally, this wouldn't be on anything user visible, except the HTML source.

Comment: The Url and the Javascript context are the only thing unique between tabs. You must use one of them, and the JS context will be erase when you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by generating a unique tab id with javascript by loading your client.

I strongly recommend you to use something for intertab communication, like [intercom.js](https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/), which can broadcast the messages from a single tab with a single connection to every other tabs. Intertab works with [socket.io](http://socket.io/), which has long polling fallback, so it may be good in your current system as well. I agree that polling is a poor choice, and you should use websockets instead.

If you use [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) on the server, then in the browser you can use [NullMQ](https://github.com/progrium/nullmq) either (for websockets ofc). I think it does not have intertab support, so you should make your own intertab solution to make it work. It is not so hard to write such a system, you need only a common storage, for example localStorage, but it can be even cookie... If you don't have a storage event, you have to ping that storage for changes with setInterval. You have to store there the messages, and which tab broadcasts them (probably in a semaphore) and when was the last time it pinged the storage. After that you can keep each tab in sync with the others, or by using a unique tab id, you can send customized messages to any of the tabs. If the broadcast tab has a storage timeout (it did not ping the storage for a long while), then it is probably closed, so you should assign the broadcast service to another tab.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was changing how my notification framework functioned in order to prevent the need for identifying unique tabs. It's just too hard to layer information on the stateless web.

Instead of using Ajax to pump messages out to the client instantly, I build them up on each page into a `List<Message>` property. On `PreRender` I render them to the client with `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`. But if I need to send the user to another page, I started using `Server.Transfer()` instead of `Response.Redirect()` instead so that it will preserve the message queue. The new page checks the old page to see if it exists and if is the correct Type. If it is the correct type, I cast it and retrieve the message queue from the old page and add them to the new page's queue. And since `Server.Transfer()` doesn't update the URL on the client, I also added a JavaScript function to manually push the state to the URL in supported browsers.

I know I took this in a little different direction than I did on the question, but I think I had been approaching it wrong in the beginning.