# C# Get Request Headers and return sorted entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

How do I read the request headers? I want to look and read for a key say "sorted" and if it is true I return a sorted version of all the books/entities. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.headers?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't seem to work for me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530041/getting-a-request-headers-value) is another old question that didn't work either as I can't compare the request header key to string or null.
This is my current code:

```
// GET: api/Books
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetAllBooks()
    {
        if (Request.Headers["sorted"] == true)
        {
         

        }
        return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Aside from the specific question, normally if someone wants to set an option like this it would be sent as a query parameter, not a header (and then it would be much easier for your code to access, since it would come in as a parameter to the method).

Comment: I get you, I would do that too and add the [FromRoute] attribute and get the value. But my assignment spec says to use HTTP Request headers. "Enhance the above API (GET /api/allbooks) to lookup a parameter in HTTP request header to weather return a sorted version of the books by title. "

Comment: Ok. Strange requirement, because it's not teaching you a normal way to do these things. A task using headers might be more useful to, say, look for an authentication token or something like that which is normally sent in the header. Anyway...to help us help you, first please tell us which version of Web API you're using here - is it ASP.NET Framework, or ASP.NET Core? And also which version of the product within that?

Comment: ASP.NET core 3.1.302 (latest), using the latest visual studio 16.7.1

Comment: Thanks. (The visual studio version is irrelevant btw, that doesn't have any effect at runtime. The code would work just the same way if you'd originally written it in Notepad). Also, how are you generating the incoming request to the API? Are you certain that the header is being set correctly in the request? (Just trying to rule out all possibilities)

Comment: I'm using Postman. Certain the request is being set correctly, in the key I add "sorted" with no quotation marks and in the value I add true.

Comment: Ok. So what happens exactly when you run the code above? Bear in mind that headers are normally treated as strings. So I'd guess either you should do `== "true")` in your if statement, or you need to extract the value, then cast it to a boolean and then do the comparison. Also you might want to consider checking the header definitely exists first, to deal with that scenario (I guess you either treat it as an error, or assume that absence of the header implies a default value of false).

Comment: I don't know to return a sorted entities array so I haven't been able to try it.

Comment: huh? You don't need to know that in order to test whether your if statement works. just use the VS debugger to test your code as it stands now. But I'm fairly sure you'll need to amend it in one of the ways I've indicated.

Comment: `if(bool.TryParse(Request.Headers["sorted"], out bool isSorted) && isSorted)` change it to this.

Comment: Why was this question posted twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411882/c-sharp-get-request-headers-and-return-sorted-list-of-entities

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411882/c-sharp-get-request-headers-and-return-sorted-list-of-entities)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# get Request headers and return sorted list of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411882/c-sharp-get-request-headers-and-return-sorted-list-of-entities)