# C# get Request headers and return sorted list of entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers

Posting again as I lost access to my initial stack overflow account. Initial question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410730/c-sharp-get-request-headers-and-return-sorted-entities). I apologize in advance for any inconveniences caused.

How do I read the request headers? I want to look and read for a key say "sorted" and if it is true I return a sorted version of all the books/entities. I'm also not sure on how to return sorted entities. I understand this seems odd but its part of my assignment spec, otherwise I'd get a parameter from the URL using the `[FromRoute]` attribute. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.headers?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't seem to work for me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530041/getting-a-request-headers-value) is another old question that didn't work either as I can't compare the request header key to string or null. This is my current code:

```
// GET: api/Books
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetAllBooks()
{
    if (Request.Headers["sorted"] == true)
    {


    }
    return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
}

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long libraryId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

> Edit: Added book entity

Comment: Did you use debugger to trace if Request.Headers actually is the array that you expect?

Comment: I don't get any errors when building if that's what you're referring to? I'm not sure what data type is returned. Microsoft docs says a name value is returned

Comment: The header value should be a string so it will never be equal to a bool. That code doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: If you use visual studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019

Comment: Would this work?                                                                                                  
 `string header = Request.Headers["sorted"];
            bool isSortedTrue;

            if (bool.TryParse(header, out isSortedTrue) && isSortedTrue)
            {
             

            }`

Comment: Do you know how to sort a list of entities (in this case, books) so I can try building and test the code?

Comment: It should work if the value of the header is "true" or "false", case insensitive. But you haven't shown what the value is. To sort a sequence you can use `.OrderBy`

Comment: How do you want the books to be sorted? By name, id, author etc. You need to provide us the book entity as well to answer it.

Comment: `      string header = Request.Headers["sorted"];
            bool isSortedTrue;

            if (bool.TryParse(header, out isSortedTrue) && isSortedTrue)
            {
                return await _context.Books.OrderBy(book => book.title).ToListAsync();
            }
            return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();` I used this and set the sorted to true when sending the request and it doesn't return true

Comment: Why was this question posted twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410730/c-sharp-get-request-headers-and-return-sorted-entities

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this:

```cs
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("sorted", out StringValues sortedValue) 
    && bool.TryParse(sortedValue, out bool isSorted))
{
     if(isSorted)
     {
          return await _context.Books.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
     }
}

return await _context.Books.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
```

the reason why you would write `TryGetValue` and `TryParse` is to avoid `exceptions` if the value is `missing/null` or if the value is not a `boolean`.

and based on your logic you can sort the books in `ascending or descending` order and on the `property` you want e.g.: Id, title, author, or publishedDate ...etc.

Or for simplicity you can change the check to:

```cs
if (bool.TryParse(Request.Headers["sorted"], out bool isSorted) && isSorted){
     return await _context.Books.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
}

return await _context.Books.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
```

#### Edit (added postman request example):

[image]

Comment: Am I supposed to use the primitives namespace to use "StringValues"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6gJ258K I don't get the list sorted. I put the headers like I have shown. And this is my code `public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> GetAllBooks()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue("sorted", out StringValues sortedValue) && bool.TryParse(sortedValue, out bool isSorted))
            {
                if (isSorted)
                {
                    return await _context.Books.OrderByDescending(a => a.title).ToListAsync();
                }
            }

            return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
        }`

Comment: it should work, the books would be sorted in a `descending` order on `Title`, which means from `[z-a]` as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Gald to hear that :D. On  a side note, it is better to implement `pagination mechanism` instead of returning all books (for better performance).