# One URL link - different endpoints

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following case:

I have one firm URL where client have to pay some bill. There is two opportunities.

1. The first one - the link is on government Web site and when client lands on firm Web site doesn't pay any fees.
2. The second one - link is for example found in Google search or copy-pasted and when client lands on firm Web site pay for sercice but with fees.

The main goal is to have one link but to know where is clicked from. There mustn't have any parameters. If someone has meet exact or same problem please give me information how to solve this requirement.

Comment: Perhaps you want to check the [Referer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530041/getting-a-request-headers-value